# Microsoft SQL Server on Linux (docker) - connection refused

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect from my Asp.Net Core app to my MSSQL which I run using docker, but I'm getting an error message:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)"

Here's my docker compose:

```
  api:
    image: api
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
    container_name: mssql
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "YourStrong!Passw0rd"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8001:1433"
```

and appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=127.0.0.1,8001;database=MyTestDb;user=sa;password=YourStrong!Passw0rd"
  }
}
```

Connection via SSMS works well, but when in my code I try to use:

```
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

I'm getting an error which I described above.

Do you know how can I handle this problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the connection string

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=127.0.0.1,8001;database=MyTestDb;user=sa;password=YourStrong!Passw0rd"
  }
}
```

In docker-compose container to container networking you are concerned about container service name and ports exposed in container itself. You don't want to consider the host port mapping from inside the container. Use below connection string

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=db, 1433;database=MyTestDb;user=sa;password=YourStrong!Passw0rd"
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but when I try to use dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate from cmd, it couldn;t find sql server instance.

Comment: Where and how are you running these commands? You should be running them inside the container and not on host. Use `docker-compose exec api bash` and executes command there or directly use `docker-compose exec api dotnet ...`

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me a bit